# Questions asked across Sites. NOT only SE sites

Tags: discussion, site-crossover

What is the usual community response to questions that are posted on other sites as well? For example if the same question is posted on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/) what would the community do? Answer the question or direct users to the other site?

I assume they would just answer it. But what if it became a common fad? If a tool was made to post questions simultaneously across these type of sites? It seems to me this would be an approach used by people who want to combine the corporate intelligence of people, regardless of which communities they are most closely tied to

Answer (score 1):

It would in most likelihood not even be noticed. Most people are not super active on more than one site.

People would just answer it and move on.

Answer (score 1):

We don't mind cross-posting across to other sites. We **do** mind however, about cross posting inside the Stack Exchange network (i.e. don't post the same question on both Stack Overflow and, say, Programmers).

If the OP is attentive enough to respond to both questions he started on the two different sites, so be it.

Answer (score 0):

Posting a question on both StackOverflow and Code Project is perfectly legitimate.

And it's perfectly acceptable (and even encouraged) for people to answer the question a second time on StackOverflow.

And as for this problem happening in mass quantities, and writing a tool for migration... We'll cross that bridge when we come to it.

I'm not quite sure what problem you're trying to solve.